# How to trap stack overflow error

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, recursion, stack-overflow

I have an recursive function with asynchronous interface that will likely exceed stack depth limits when called:

```
function f(x, cb) {
    if (x === 0) {
        cb();
    } else {
        f(x - 1, cb);
    }
}

f(1e6, function() {
    console.log('done');
});  // BOOM
```

(and yes, it has to be recursive, rewriting it to be iterative is not viable).

I can solve this by doing recursive call asynchronously (e.g. via `setTimeout` or `window.postMessage`, which is supposedly faster):

```
function f(x, cb) {
    if (x === 0) {
        cb();
    } else {
        setTimeout(function() {
            f(x - 1, cb);
        }, 0);
    }
}

f(1e6, function() {
    console.log('done');
});  // ok
```

But this is significantly slower. So I want to do the asynchronous call only when it would otherwise cause a stack overflow. Something like

```
function f(x, cb) {
    if (x === 0) {
        cb();
    } else {
        if (getCurrentStackDepth() == getMaxStackDepth() - 42)
            setTimeout(function() {
                f(x - 1, cb);
            }, 0);
        } else {
            f(x - 1, cb);
        }
    }
}
```

or, if this is not possible, at least detect when an overflow happens, and retry asynchronously. Something along the lines of

```
function f(x, cb) {
    if (x === 0) {
        cb();
    } else {
        try {
            f(x - 1, cb);
        } catch (e) {
            if (isStackOverflowError(e)) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    f(x - 1, cb);
                }, 0);
            } else {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can this be done? Solution via `Function.prototype.caller` is not acceptable, as I am in es5-es6 strict mode. I would prefer a portable solution, but really only need one for chrome.

Comment: It's much easier to rewrite the recursion as a loop. And yes, you said it *must* be recursive, but when you use `setTimeout` like that it won't be recursive anymore.

Comment: @Kenney this is an example, I actually have about a dozen mutually recursive asynchronous branching functions.

Comment: Okay. Resorting to `setTimeout` to avoid a stackoverflow is a bad decision, IMHO. Your original function basically comes down to `for ( ; x >0; x--) {}; cb();`. (Btw, you do realize that your top function is not asynchronous?)

Comment: @Kenney I hope it's clearer now. Stop trying to solve different problem.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no method exposed(JS) by browser to check call stack size, like you said `getCurrentStackDepth`. I tried finding it out and couldn't get any information related to it.

The last solution can be one of the way you can solve this issue. The typeof of exception object thrown by JS engine for stack size exceed is [RangeError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RangeError). So using that information and exception's message information, we can write isStackOverflowError method as shown below

```
function isStackOverflowError(e) {
    return (e instanceof RangeError) && /.+stack.+size.+/.test(e.message);
}
```

Also, this has better performance compared to example-2, but still not too fast. I will try to update if I find better way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it:

```
function f(x, cb) {
    if (x === 0) {
        cb();
    } else {
      try {
        f(x - 1, cb);
      } catch (e) {
        setTimeout( function() { f(x-1, cb); }, 0 );
      }
    }
}

f(100000,function(){console.log("Done!")})
```

However, a stack overflow is a programming error, and I can't really recommend solving it this way. It is far better to refactor the recursive code to be iterative, as they are functionally equivalent. The iterative version would use a 'stack' allocated from the heap, which can be far larger than a typical process stack.

See [Recursion versus iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29#Recursion_versus_iteration) for more information.